# Reference to service becomes null

Tags: android

I have an activity that starts and binds to a service. I enable the Don't Keep Activities option in Developer Options of the phone to test this.

When I run the app the first time both the activity and the service starts. I can use the app without problems. Then I hit the home button and both the activity and service are killed instantly. Then I launch the app again, the activity starts as normal, service starts and gets bound as normal, and the service instance is saved in the musicService variable as normal. Then I use the activity which tries to call a method on musicService and it crashes because musicService is null.

I am starting the service  and binding to it in onStart of my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initMusicService();
}

private void initMusicService() {

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(onMediaPlayerPlayingReceiver,
            new IntentFilter("MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYING"));

    if (musicServiceIntent == null) {

        musicServiceIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(musicServiceIntent, musicServiceConnection, 0);
        startService(musicServiceIntent);

    }

}
```

And then I am saving a reference to the service when it's connected:

```
private ServiceConnection musicServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {

        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder) service;
        musicService = binder.getService();
       ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {

        tabPagerAdapter.getNowPlayingFragment().unbindController();

    }
};
```

And this is the onDestroy method of my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    unbindService(musicServiceConnection);
    stopService(musicServiceIntent);
    musicService = null;

    super.onDestroy();

}
```

This is the error in logcat:

```
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.zezo.music.MusicPlayerActivity$2.onReceive(MusicPlayerActivity.java:101)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-01 07:41:25.393: E/AndroidRuntime(20592):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I use breakpoints after activity is relaunched and see that onServiceConnected is called, `musicService = binder.getService();`  is run and musicService is not null.

In the same activity I have:

```
public void play(Song song) {

    if (song != null && musicService.audioFocusGranted()) {
        musicService.playSong(song);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Playing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

and

```
private BroadcastReceiver onMediaPlayerPlayingReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {

        if (i.getAction() != "MEDIA_PLAYER_PLAYING")
            return;

        Song song = musicService.getCurrentSong();

       ...

    }
};
```

After relaunch, musicService in the play method is not null and the service assigned to it works fine but the one in onReceive is null. And the musicService is a member on the activity instance so it should have the same value in both methods. Somehow it is as if it first gets assigned but then gets unassigned between the calls or gets assigned in an activity instance but gets called in the destroyed instance of the same activity somehow.

The manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.zezo.music"
    android:versionCode="155"
    android:versionName="1.55">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<!-- Soft input delete key not working bug above target 13 and above min 8. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
    <activity
        android:name="com.zezo.music.MusicPlayerActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name="com.zezo.music.MusicService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.zezo.zezomusicplayer.MusicService.BIND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
            <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.zezo.music.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Please add logs also.

Comment: Also are you sure you updated Service reference after Activity was recreated?

Comment: Added the logs and yes service reference is updated I check it with a breakpoint inside onServiceConnected

Comment: Add breakpoints on each assignment of `musicService` weather null or a reference.

Comment: MusicService is probably fine. The problem might be that broadcastreceiver might run in a different process. Can you post your manifest?

Comment: @aycanadal Try `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` within activity if it is what @breakline has suggested.

Comment: Added the manifest, singleInstance does not fix the problem.

Comment: Did you add a null check in `onReceive()` and then checked if it still works? Add `if(musicService == null) return;`

Comment: Also unregister the receiver in `onDestroy()`.

Comment: @Abbas please enter what you said as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason an `Activity` should register `BroadcastReceivers` is to use the events in some way on the current activity, to inform the User of an event. If `onPause()` has been called, then the Activity is no longer in the foreground, and therefore can't update the User.

You should register and unregister your receivers in `onStart()` and `onStop()`. `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called, and you could continue receiving broadcasts for a long time, even when the Activity is no longer open.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that binding to a `Service` is asynchronous and you are trying to use it from a `BroadcastReceiver` which is not tied to the binding. This is why when you call `bindService()` you provide a `ServiceConnection`. When `onServiceDisconnected()` is called, you need to clear your `Binder` reference as it no longer exists (though that is not your current issue.)

The simplest way to resolve this with this code is don't register the receiver until `onServiceConnected()` is called. You could also add some tracking of media state and in the receiver only call to the service if it is non-null and in the `onServiceConnected()` check to see if you have state information available which you need to pass to the service immediately.

Comment: I tried registering the receiver inside onServiceConnected() but the musicService in onReceive() is still null the second time app is launched after killed by OS.

Comment: What you're saying makes total sense and I am doing it that way now but unregistering the receiver like @Abbas said fixed the problem.

Comment: Glad you were able to get passed it. The async nature of services and receivers makes these interactions interesting. Even if that wasn't what was biting you this time, it likely would have surfaced at some point.